# First meaningful paint "candidate" vs first meaningful paint?

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

What is a first meaningful paint (FMP) candidate as noted my Chrome Developer Tools? How does this differ from the first meaningful paint?

[image]

As you can see the yellow lines are the FMPs, the first two being labelled "candidates" with the last just being the FMP. What flags the first two as possible FMPs and what stops them from being the real one, is it just a repaint or reflow after that point that makes it not count?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I looked into this and eventually discovered with the help of a DevTools teammate that it's a bug. See https://crbug.com/753435. Those events are only supposed to be visible if you have a certain experiment enabled. They're behind an experiment because, as you found out for yourself, the results are often confusing / incoherent.